# Angular 2, adding active class to router link [Best practice]

Tags: angular, routerlinkactive

I'm using the `Input`routerLinkActive to add active class to some specific url.
But I want that specific link is always active if it detect a chunck of word.
Let I explain:
if my defined route is `/rent/page/:id`, and into my template, I do this:

```
 <a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/rent/page/1']" title="">rent</a>
```

It works if the url in the adress bar match the defined route, and it adds `active` class.
My main navigation which contains **rent link will be active**.

But I want more, if my routed has this definition `/rent/:property/:name/:id`,
and I tap the url, it doesn't add the active link to my main navigation.

I found the following solution:

```
   // ...
   this._router.events.subscribe(
        (urlObj) => {
            if(urlObj.url.match(/^(\/rent).*$/)) {
                this.active["rent"] = true;
            }
        }
    )
    // ...
```

Every time I match `rent` into the current url, I set property `rent` to the object `active` and it adds active to my rent navigation.
And the template mentionned before, I change it as follow:

```
<a [class.active]="active['rent']" [routerLink]="['/rent/page/1']" title="">rent</a>
```

And it works, but I'm not sure, if this is a good practice or not.

My question is: **How to `routerLinkActive` if I want to keep specific link active, even if user changes the page? Is there an alternative way to do this using `[routerLinkActive]` ?**

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this with router-link:

```
<router-link :to="{name :'root'}">Root</router-link>
<router-link :to="{name :'foo'}">Go to Foo</router-link>
<router-link to="to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
```

/bar">Go to Bar

Checkout the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xgrjzsup/3276/